# How to get Author data into Google search results without Microformats?

Tags: microformats

First, I apologize if this is not considered `programming` related enough for some peoples taste, however I feel it is appropriate as my question is related to what you put in a websites markup, I think so anyways.

Ok so I searched Google for the term `dribbble invite` and on page 2 of my results, or at this URL [Google result](https://www.google.com/search?rlz=1C1CHFX_enUS401US401&aq=f&gcx=w&sourceid=chrome&ie=UTF-8&q=dribbble%20invite#q=dribbble%20invite&hl=en&rlz=1C1CHFX_enUS401US401&prmd=imvns&ei=dfnUTpvJGcLZtgfDzeSUAg&start=10&sa=N&bav=on.2,or.r_gc.r_pw.r_cp.,cf.osb&fp=eace23dd34db2182&biw=1280&bih=856)  the 5th result on page 2 (will probably be different for you based on your location and other factors) There is a result like the image below

[image: search]

Notice the author Photo and name.  I am looking for how to do this with a website?  From my research in the past it looks like it is done with Microformats however a search through the source code of the page [HERE](http://imjustcreative.com/two-dribbble-invites-giveaway/2010/06/03/) does not appear to be using any Microformats.

Any idea how this is happening for that website?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Typically, this is done through Google+.

There's a pretty good article on how-to here :

http://www.labnol.org/internet/author-profile-in-google/19775/